# Need different elements in ArrayList<ModelClass>

Tags: java, android

I am developing an app in android studio that takes movie names and places them onto cards that swipe left and right. I am having a problem with my MovieList, it will populate but the same movie name goes into it 20 times rather than what I want which is 20 different movie names from the TMDB API. I just created this new MyAdapter class also. So I am not sure why I am not getting different elements into the list. When I use string instead of my MovieModelClass it gets different elements. OnPostExecute is where I loop through the title and add it to the array

Heres my MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private MyAdapter adapter;
    private ArrayList<MovieModelClass> movieList = new ArrayList<>();
  
    SwipeFlingAdapterView flingContainer;

    private static String JSON_URL = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=8099f5720bad1f61f020fdbc855f73db";
    //List<MovieModelClass> movieList;
    //@InjectView(R.id.frame) SwipeFlingAdapterView flingContainer;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        
        flingContainer = (SwipeFlingAdapterView) findViewById(R.id.frame);
        
        GetData getData = new GetData();
        getData.execute();

     
        flingContainer.setFlingListener(new SwipeFlingAdapterView.onFlingListener() {
           
            @Override
            public void removeFirstObjectInAdapter() {
              
              Log.d("LIST", "removed object!");
               movieList.remove(0);
              adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onLeftCardExit(Object dataObject) {
                
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "left", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onRightCardExit(Object dataObject) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "right", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdapterAboutToEmpty(int itemsInAdapter) {
            
            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(float scrollProgressPercent) {
              
            }


        });

        // Optionally add an OnItemClickListener
        flingContainer.setOnItemClickListener(new SwipeFlingAdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClicked(int itemPosition, Object dataObject) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });


    }

    public class GetData extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

            String current = "";

            try {
                URL url;
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

                try {

                    url = new URL(JSON_URL);
                    urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                    InputStream is = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);

                    int data = isr.read();
                    while (data != -1) {
                        current += (char) data;
                        data = isr.read();
                    }

                    return current;

                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    if (urlConnection != null) {
                        //  urlConnection.disconnect();
                    }
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return current;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull String s){

            try{
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");

                movieList = new ArrayList<>();

                MovieModelClass model = new MovieModelClass();

                for(int i = 0; i< jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                   
                     model.setName(jsonObject1.getString("title"));
                                
                    movieList.add(model);
                }
         

                adapter = new MyAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.item, movieList);
                flingContainer.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
    }
```

and this is MyAdapter class which I use for the arrayAdapter

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<MovieModelClass> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
    }


    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


       MovieModelClass movies = (MovieModelClass) getItem(position);

       if(convertView == null)
       {
           convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
       }

       TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);

       name.setText(movies.getName());

       return convertView ;
    }
}
```

and my model class

```
public class MovieModelClass {
    String name;

    public MovieModelClass(String id) {
        this.name = name;  
    }
    public MovieModelClass() {

    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that your [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Can you do yet smaller?

Comment: @OleV.V. yeah thats pretty much bare bones as is, I need basically everything there to actually run and view the cards. Maybe a few variables I left I can take them out now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Java reference variable will point an Object unless reassigned

The code below

1. creates a single model object `MovieModelClass model = new MovieModelClass();` and assigns to reference `model`
2. inside the for loop, the same object is updated and added to arraylist
3. this results in multiple occurrence of the same object inside `List` (its only a single object that is referenced multiple times inside the List)

```java
movieList = new ArrayList<>();

MovieModelClass model = new MovieModelClass();

for(int i = 0; i< jsonArray.length(); i++) {
  JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
  model.setName(jsonObject1.getString("title"));
  movieList.add(model);
}
```

Especially, this part of the `MovieModelClass model = new MovieModelClass();` should be moved inside the loop

### Fix

```java
movieList = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 0; i< jsonArray.length(); i++) {
  JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
  MovieModelClass model = new MovieModelClass();
  model.setName(jsonObject1.getString("title"));
  movieList.add(model);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much that worked! and I really appreciate the explanation. It makes much more sense. I can't believe I didn't see that. Just staring at the code too long.